# How to use Unity project with Travis Ci?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sh, travis-ci, pipeline

I was following this guide:

https://jonathan.porta.codes/2015/04/17/automatically-build-your-unity3d-project-in-the-cloud-using-travisci-for-free/

What I wanna do is to test a unity project with Travic Ci. I am trying all the time to make it work. Maybi someone here have some idea how it works but it doesn't work very well. I dont know how to fix this problem. I stuck all the time with the same error like:

```
$ ./scripts/install.sh
Downloading from http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/3757309da7e7/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.2.2f1.pkg: 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16  100    16    0     0    774      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   761
Installing Unity.pkg
installer: Error the package path specified was invalid: 'Unity.pkg'.
install: editor,: No such file or directory
install: windowssupport,: No such file or directory
install: linuxsupport,: No such file or directory
The command "./scripts/install.sh" failed and exited with 71 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

This is my script file install.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Example install script for Unity3D project. See the entire example: https://github.com/JonathanPorta/ci-build

# This link changes from time to time. I haven't found a reliable hosted installer package for doing regular
# installs like this. You will probably need to grab a current link from: http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
echo 'Downloading from http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/3757309da7e7/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.2.2f1.pkg: '
curl -o Unity.pkg http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/3757309da7e7/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.2.2f1.pkg

echo 'Installing Unity.pkg'
sudo installer -dumplog -package Unity.pkg -target /
```

And this is my build.sh file:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Example build script for Unity3D project. See the entire example: https://github.com/JonathanPorta/ci-build

# Change this the name of your project. This will be the name of the final executables as well.
project="ci-build"

echo "Attempting to build $project for Windows"
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity \
  -batchmode \
  -nographics \
  -silent-crashes \
  -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log \
  -projectPath $(pwd) \
  -buildWindowsPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/windows/$project.exe" \
  -quit

echo "Attempting to build $project for OS X"
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity \
  -batchmode \
  -nographics \
  -silent-crashes \
  -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log \
  -projectPath $(pwd) \
  -buildOSXUniversalPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/osx/$project.app" \
  -quit

echo "Attempting to build $project for Linux"
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity \
  -batchmode \
  -nographics \
  -silent-crashes \
  -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log \
  -projectPath $(pwd) \
  -buildLinuxUniversalPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/linux/$project.exe" \
  -quit

echo 'Logs from build'
cat $(pwd)/unity.log
```

I hope if someone can help me with this problem !?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the logs:

```
Installing Unity.pkg
installer: Error the package path specified was invalid: 'Unity.pkg'.
install: editor,: No such file or directory
```

Seems like the problem is the UnityInstaller. 
In your script you are trying to download `Unity-5.2.2f1.pkg`.
if you go to that address you will see that the file requested doesn't exist on that URL.

```
curl http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/3757309da7e7/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.2.2f1.pkg

File not found."
```

And that is the first problem that you have to solve.

Now, Unity 5.2 is a pretty old version, and that tutorial was written in *Apr 17, 2015*, I would sugest to complement that tutorial with a newer one.

Comment: Thank you @Mayo. This is very clear to me. In these couplse days I will looking at this and solve the first problem and go further.